# What's the best way to achieve this kind of grid template

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm facing a problem with creating this kind of grid template by the simplest way. I've tried to find something similar to this that would help me but I've found nothing. Image below presents the behaviors:

1. Full screen size
2. Medium screen size
3. Small screen size (mobile)

Image presents full viewport. First element should always be the same size (300px x 300px) and in the same position but sibling elements should behave as shown on image. Sibling elements should behave as css `grid-template-columns` with `auto-fit` and `minmax()` should be 200px (min) and 300px (max). The first thing I did was to create something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="big-div"></div>
  <div class="grid">
      <div class="grid-element"></div>
      <div class="grid-element"></div>
      <div class="grid-element"></div>
      <div class="grid-element"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But this behaves like 2 columns so elements from grid will not wrap around big div. My another option was to create something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="big-div"></div>
  <div class="sibling-wrapper">
      <div class="element"></div>
      <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="sibling-wrapper">
      <div class="element"></div>
      <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in this case I wanted to use `display: flex` with `flex-wrap: wrap` option so it would behave almost as I want to but after first sibling-wrapper wrap to another line I have to change its flex direction to be row and not column. I think I can achieve it using this case but maybe there is anything clearer?

[image]

Comment: In terms of the viewport, what size should those elements, or that grid, be? What did you try, and where did you get stuck? What's your specific (representative) HTML structure?

Comment: @DavidThomas I've edited my question with more detailed informations

Comment: Where's your CSS? CSS Grid seems to be the way to solve this easily.

Comment: Please be more explicit about your required styling. If your big element is always 300px by 300px you diagrams indicate that media breakpoints would be slightly greater than 900px, slightly greater than 600px and that you aren’t going to be interested in a viewport less than 300px wide. But what do you actually want. How flexible are those other elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi achieving this kind of template with grid is very easy please go through any grid tutorial meanwhile here is a sample of what you wanted, tried to be as simple as possible and also you can play with the code for your specific width and height or colors.

```css
.grid-element1 {
  grid-area: head;
  /* ANY NAME CAN BE GIVEN TO IDENTIFY LIKE I USED HEAD 
                          BOTTOM MAIN ETC */
}

.grid-element2 {
  grid-area: main;
}

.grid-element3 {
  grid-area: bottom;
}

.grid-element4 {
  grid-area: side1;
}

.grid-element5 {
  grid-area: side2;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "head head main main bottom bottom" "head head side1 side1 side2 side2";
  gap: 10px;
}

.grid>div {
  background-color: rgba(183, 39, 39, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
  /* CODE FOR YOUR SECOND LAYOUT */
  .grid {
    grid-template-areas: "head head main main" "head head bottom bottom" "side1 side1 side2 side2";
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  /* CODE FOR YOUR THIRDLAYOUT */
  .grid {
    grid-template-areas: "head head" "head head" "main main" "bottom bottom" "side1 side1" "side2 side2";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="big-div"></div>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-element1">head</div>
    <div class="grid-element2">main</div>
    <div class="grid-element3">bottom</div>
    <div class="grid-element4">side1</div>
    <div class="grid-element5">side2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this solves your query

Comment: That is my second time with css grid so I didn't even knew that I can achieve this almost only with grid-template-areas. Thanks a lot for your help. I'll go through grid tutorials for sure!

Comment: Its fine , you can start from here you'll understand most of the things then practice https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

Comment: @Sameer w3schools is a terrible resource. I would strongly recommend CSS Tricks instead https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: @disinfor I know but for starter its fine and even CSS tricks is not that complete you'll need multiple resources to study anyways. Its upto the learner's choice what tutorial he/she finds more easy to grasp.